# Vulnerability Using AES128 with ECB mode of operation

Tags: security, encryption, hash, aes

> I need to implement a system where, I will generate a userId/password combination for a user. The userId will be generated using some common logic for all the users.
>
> For Example, the userId will be user's `<mobileNumber>_XYZ`.
>
> The password for the user will be generated by **Encrypting** `userId` with`AES128 encryption with ECB mode`.
>
> The user will have access to his userId/password. He can find it in the headers (This is because of some third party tool we are using. You can ignore this part.)

**Following are the vulnerabilities that I can find in it:**

1. Since each userId has `_XYZ` as the suffix, all the passwords will
       have same block in the end. And in few turns the    attacker will
       know that the password is nothing but some encryption of the
       userId only.
2. He can guess that it might be `AES128 Encryption with ECB`.

> My concern here is that if **he is not able to get his hands** on the `KEY` which we have used for encryption, is there a way for the attacker to crack our system?

Comment: You've asked a lot of questions now regarding this.  I feel like you're asking about an XY problem.  Rather than asking about how you think you can solve the problem, just ask about the problem itself.  What are you actually trying to implement?  What do you want your system to be able to do and what attacks are you trying to avoid?  Edit your question to include this information and you might find there is a better way to achieve what you want to do.

Answer (score 2):

If the user ID is split across multiple ECB blocks, an attacker can "mix and match" encrypted blocks to guess passwords for user IDs similar to their own. For instance, if the user ID was split as:

```
"user_123", "45" -> "ABCD", "EFGH"
"user_456", "78" -> "IJKL", "MNOP"
```

then an attacker could conceivably guess that the password `ABCDMNOP` would be valid for user `user_12378`.

The simplest solution is to not use AES-ECB. Use a (keyed) HMAC construction to derive a password from the user ID; this is secure, although it does not allow the user ID to be determined from the password. (Which is probably fine.)